# iOS 9.3.5 Apple Music can't play albums any more

Tags: ios, apple-music

The first song repeats forever. When I manually select the second song, that repeats forever. See screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

See screenshot. This has been happening since I downgraded from iOS 8.4.? to 9.3.5.

Is there any known solution, other than "wait for an update"?

For US$10.00/month, I like to think I can expect as much as my 8 track player was capable of when I was in the 7th grade.

Comment: Did you disable Repeat Song? (Exit out of Up Next and at the bottom ensure that repeat is turned off) Also did you upgrade or downgrade?

Comment: @brick I chose to call it a downgrade. You read the version numbers correctly. You guessed correctly that Repeat Song was enabled. That fixed it. Thank you. God knows how it happened, but it could could only have been me. Presumably orthogonal to the OS change (at least it'd better be). If you submit that as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do check that Repeat Song is disabled. Exit out of Up Next and ensure that Repeat is turned off.